# Ruby create and open file with ::expand_path and create directory with ::expand_path

Tags: ruby, file, io, directory

I'm just beginning to learn file IO with Ruby, and had a question about being able to use ::expand_path to direct to a path separate from where my program is running.

Here is what I essentially would *like* to be able to do, but this unfortunately does not work for me.

```
require 'openuri'
require 'fileutils'

if File.expand_path.exists?("~/newpathdir/")
        File.expand_path.open("~/newpathdir/log.txt", "a+") {|f| f.write("#{Time.now}       Directory is good.  Returning...") }        #If directory is present, does nothing
        return
    else
        FileUtils.mkdir_p.expand_path("~/newpathdir/")
        File.open("~/newpathdir/log.txt", "a+") {|f| f.write("#{Time.now}       Directory not found.  Creating...") }       #If directory not found, writes to log
    end

def writeLatestToFile
    tweet_file = File.open("~/newpathdir/latest_tweet.txt", "a+")       #Opens file
        if tweet_file       #Checks if file opened correctly
            tweet_file.syswrite("#{@latest_tweet["ID"]}\n#{@latest_tweet["Tweet"]}")        #Appends latest_command information to latest_command.txt
        elsif
            File.open("~/newpathdir/log.txt", 'a+') {|f| f.write("#{Time.now}       Error opening tweet_file.txt") }        #If error in opening file, writes to log
        end
end
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How does this not work? What problems are you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
require 'fileutils'

def append(path, message)
  path = File.expand_path path
  FileUtils.mkdir_p File.dirname(path)
  File.open(path, "a+") {|f| f.write "#{message}\n" }
end

def log(path, message)
  append(path, "#{Time.now} #{message}")
end

append('~/newpathdir/latest_tweet', "123456\nLatestTweet")
log('~/newpathdir/log', 'Hello world')
```

Maybe you should also try `Logger`. [Class: Logger (Ruby 1.9.3)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html)

```
require 'logger'
require 'fileutils'

path = File.expand_path '~/newnewpathdir/tweets_logger.log'
FileUtils.mkdir_p File.dirname(path)
log = Logger.new(path)

log.debug('Hello world.')
log.info('Info message.')
log.error('Error message.')
```